# How to override core plugin method?

Tags: overrides, magento2.4, core, around-plugin

I would like to override core plugin method
Core plugin path

Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\StockState\CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin.php

In this file I would like to override `aroundCheckQuoteItemQty()` function and I refer all the related links solutions in `magento.stackexchange.com` but no luck

in my `di.xml` file

```
<type name="Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\StockState\CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin">
        <plugin name="check_quote_item_qty" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="vendor_name_check_quote_item_qty" type="Vendor\Name\Model\Plugin\StockState\CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin" sortOrder="99" />
    </type>
```

Here is my custom plugin code and I  put `die()` function in `aroundCheckQuoteItemQty` function but why it is not overrding

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Name\Model\Plugin\StockState;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\Factory as ObjectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface;
use Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\GetSkusByProductIdsInterface;
use Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition;
use Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\ProductSalabilityError;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\SalesChannelInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\StockState\CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin as coreCheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin;
/**
 * Replace legacy quote item check
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */

class CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectFactory
     */
    private $objectFactory;

    /**
     * @var FormatInterface
     */
    private $format;

    /**
     * @var AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface
     */
    private $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty;

    /**
     * @var IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var GetSkusByProductIdsInterface
     */
    private $getSkusByProductIds;

    /**
     * @var StockResolverInterface
     */
    private $stockResolver;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition
     */
    private $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition;

    /**
     * @param ObjectFactory $objectFactory
     * @param FormatInterface $format
     * @param AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty
     * @param IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestFactory
     * @param GetSkusByProductIdsInterface $getSkusByProductIds
     * @param StockResolverInterface $stockResolver
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        FormatInterface $format,
        AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty,
        IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestFactory,
        GetSkusByProductIdsInterface $getSkusByProductIds,
        StockResolverInterface $stockResolver,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition
    ) {  die('call plugin');
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
        $this->format = $format;
        $this->areProductsSalableForRequestedQty = $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty;
        $this->isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory = $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestFactory;
        $this->getSkusByProductIds = $getSkusByProductIds;
        $this->stockResolver = $stockResolver;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition = $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition;
    }

    /**
     * Replace legacy quote item check
     *
     * @param StockStateInterface $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param int $productId
     * @param float $itemQty
     * @param float $qtyToCheck
     * @param float $origQty
     * @param int|null $scopeId
     *
     * @return DataObject
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundCheckQuoteItemQty(
        StockStateInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $productId,
        $itemQty,
        $qtyToCheck,
        $origQty,
        $scopeId = null
    ) {die('call plugin');
         $result = $this->objectFactory->create();
        $result->setHasError(false);

        $qty = max($this->getNumber($itemQty), $this->getNumber($qtyToCheck));

        $skus = $this->getSkusByProductIds->execute([$productId]);
        $productSku = $skus[$productId];

        $websiteCode = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($scopeId)->getCode();
        $stock = $this->stockResolver->execute(SalesChannelInterface::TYPE_WEBSITE, $websiteCode);
        $stockId = $stock->getStockId();

        $request = $this->isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory->create(
            [
                'sku' => $productSku,
                'qty' => $qty,
            ]
        );
        $productsSalableResult = $this->areProductsSalableForRequestedQty->execute([$request], (int)$stockId);
        
        $productsSalableResult = current($productsSalableResult);

        if ($productsSalableResult->isSalable() === false) {
            /** @var ProductSalabilityError $error */
            foreach ($productsSalableResult->getErrors() as $error) {
                $result->setHasError(true)->setMessage($error->getMessage())->setQuoteMessage("Some of the products are out of stock.")
                    ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
            }
        } else {
            $productSalableResult = $this->backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition->execute($productSku, (int)$stockId, $qty);
            if ($productSalableResult->getErrors()) {
                /** @var ProductSalabilityError $error */
                foreach ($productSalableResult->getErrors() as $error) {
                    $result->setMessage($error->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Convert quantity to a valid float
     *
     * @param string|float|int|null $qty
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    private function getNumber($qty)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($qty)) {
            return $this->format->getNumber($qty);
        }

        return $qty;
    }
}
```

Comment: why you want to overide corre plugin instade of orignal method?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution for override the file

```
app/code/Vendor/Name/etc/di.xml


<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface">
     <plugin name="check_quote_item_qty" disabled="true" />
            <plugin name="check_quote_item_qty_custom" type="Vendor\Name\Plugin\StockState\CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin"/>
     </type>
</config>
```

Here is the following file

```
app\code\Vendor\Name\Plugin\StockState\CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin.php


<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Name\Plugin\StockState;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\Factory as ObjectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface;
use Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\GetSkusByProductIdsInterface;
use Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableCondition\BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition;
use Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\ProductSalabilityError;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\SalesChannelInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * Replace legacy quote item check
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectFactory
     */
    private $objectFactory;

    /**
     * @var FormatInterface
     */
    private $format;

    /**
     * @var AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface
     */
    private $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty;

    /**
     * @var IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var GetSkusByProductIdsInterface
     */
    private $getSkusByProductIds;

    /**
     * @var StockResolverInterface
     */
    private $stockResolver;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition
     */
    private $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition;

    /**
     * @param ObjectFactory $objectFactory
     * @param FormatInterface $format
     * @param AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty
     * @param IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestFactory
     * @param GetSkusByProductIdsInterface $getSkusByProductIds
     * @param StockResolverInterface $stockResolver
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        FormatInterface $format,
        AreProductsSalableForRequestedQtyInterface $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty,
        IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestFactory,
        GetSkusByProductIdsInterface $getSkusByProductIds,
        StockResolverInterface $stockResolver,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        BackOrderNotifyCustomerCondition $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition
    ) {
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
        $this->format = $format;
        $this->areProductsSalableForRequestedQty = $areProductsSalableForRequestedQty;
        $this->isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestInterfaceFactory = $isProductSalableForRequestedQtyRequestFactory;
        $this->getSkusByProductIds = $getSkusByProductIds;
        $this->stockResolver = $stockResolver;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition = $backOrderNotifyCustomerCondition;
    }

    /**
     * Replace legacy quote item check
     *
     * @param StockStateInterface $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param int $productId
     * @param float $itemQty
     * @param float $qtyToCheck
     * @param float $origQty
     * @param int|null $scopeId
     *
     * @return DataObject
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundCheckQuoteItemQty(
        StockStateInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $productId,
        $itemQty,
        $qtyToCheck,
        $origQty,
        $scopeId = null
    ) {
        $result = $this->objectFactory->create();
        $result->setHasError(false);

        die('core plugin');

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Convert quantity to a valid float
     *
     * @param string|float|int|null $qty
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    private function getNumber($qty)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($qty)) {
            return $this->format->getNumber($qty);
        }

        return $qty;
    }
}
```